# Keras Cropping2D changes color channel

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I tried to visualize the effect of keras cropping 2D using the following code snippet:

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers.convolutional import Cropping2D
from keras.models import Sequential
# with a Sequential model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Cropping2D(cropping=((22, 0), (0, 0)), input_shape=(160, 320, 3)))
cropping_output = K.function([model.layers[0].input],
                                  [model.layers[0].output])
cropped_image = cropping_output([image[None,...]])[0]
compare_images(image,
               cropped_image.reshape(cropped_image.shape[1:]))
```

Here is the plotting function:

```
def compare_images(left_image, right_image):    
    print(image.shape)
    f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(24, 9))
    f.tight_layout()
    ax1.imshow(left_image)
    ax1.set_title('Shape '+ str(left_image.shape),
                  fontsize=50)
    ax2.imshow(right_image)
    ax2.set_title('Shape '+ str(right_image.shape)
                  , fontsize=50)
    plt.show()
```

The result is

[image]

Obviously, the color channel has been changed. But why? Is there an error in my code or could that be a keras bug?

Comment: How did you plot these images?

Comment: I edited it into the original question

Comment: For some reason matplotlib is sometimes taking a negative of the picture instead of original picture. Could you compare the actual values in both of pictures and check if they are different?

Answer (score 1):

Its not a Keras bug. Tensors are usually of `float32` type so when the output is evaluated they are also of `float32` type. You need to convert the image data to `uint8` type before displaying.

```
ax2.imshow(np.uint8(right_image))
```

in `compare_images` should display the image correctly.